# Replace form index ID after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Within a Project form, a user can clone any specific task -- this is working fine.  I now need to replace the copied task's index ID (which is a time stamp) with a new time stamp.  My current code only replaces a single div.

How can I replace all form input/label field IDs with a timestamp?  I current do a find() and then replace.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on('click', '.clone-task', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    var taskCopy = $(this).parents(".dupForm").clone();
    $("#dupTask").append(workoutCopy);
    var attributes = taskCopy.find('input').attr('name').replace(/\[\d+]/g, time);
      alert(attributes);
    });
 });
```

Task Form (ruby-on-rails):

```
 <fieldset>
 <div class="field">
 <b><%= f.label :name, "Major Task" %></b> | 
 <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "task name" %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
 <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :time_start, "Scheduled Time" %><br />
 <%= f.time_select :time_start, {:ampm => true, :minute_step => 15} %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :task_duration, "Task Duration(mins)" %>
 <%= f.number_field :task_duration, size: 3 %>
 </div>
 <b>Add Supporting Actions to Your Task</b> 
 <%= f.fields_for :activities do |builder| -%>
 <%= render 'activity_fields', f: builder %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Action", f, :activities %>
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `attr()` method allows you to use a function as argument which will act as a loop to process all matched elements.

```
taskCopy.find('input').attr('name', function( idx, name){
    return name.replace(/\[\d+]/g, time);
});
```

API refrence:  http://api.jquery.com/attr/